# Client side - call to function

Tags: jquery, ajax, entity-framework, jquery-events

`GetTaskProgress` gets `date1` and receives `driverid`, `pdrivername`, `ordercount` and `oordercountwherename isnotnull` - I have a syntax error which cannot call my function and receive data.
Please check my code here:

```
   _Services.invoke({
                 method: 'GetTaskProgress',
                 data: { xDATEx: date1 },
                 success: function (q) {
                      paint(q);
                 }
```

This is the function that needs to be called:

```
 function paint(orders) {
         var table = $('#progressgrid')
                        '<table>';
            $.each(orders, function() {
                        table +=
                                    '<tr>'+
                                                '<td>'+this.DriverId +'</td>'+
                                                '<td>'+this.PdriverName +'</td>'+
                                                '<td>'+this.OrderCount +'</td>'+
                                                '<td>'+this.OrderCountWhereNameIsNotNull +'</td>'+
                                    '</tr>';
            });
            table+=
                        '</table>';
            table=$(progressgrid);
            div.append(table);
}
```

This is my client div:

```
<div id="progressgrid"></div>
```

Comment: what does the syntax error say

Comment: thats the prob...no syntax errors it just dont work at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `div` from `div.append(table)` isn't defined. Shouldn't be a syntax error, but it is an error. the invoke method is also missing a closing `}` and `)` (in your first example)

```
_Services.invoke({
    method: 'GetTaskProgress',
    data: { xDATEx: date1 },
    success: function (q) {
        paint(q);
    }
})
```

and

```
function paint(orders) {
    var table = '<table>';
    var div = $("#progressgrid");
    $.each(orders, function() {
        table += '<tr>'+
                 '<td>'+this.DriverId +'</td>'+
                 '<td>'+this.PdriverName +'</td>'+
                 '<td>'+this.OrderCount +'</td>'+
                 '<td>'+this.OrderCountWhereNameIsNotNull +'</td>'+
                 '</tr>';
    });
    table += '</table>';
    div.append(table);
}
```

Comment: <div id="progressgrid"></div> how do i defined the div?  table=$(progressgrid);
            div.append(table);   ?

Comment: var div = $("#progressgrid");

Comment: i have updated the code. i do not understand where the var goes? can you update the code or paste it here on my code pleeas